# Can an attacker steal one's credentials if they never ask for it?

Tags: attacks, phishing

Can a website that never asks for one's credentials still steal one's credentials?

If yes, how?

Comment: This is now far too open-ended. There are numerous ways to gather credentials. Exploiting browser vulnerabilities is top of the list.